# libgcc_s.so: undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail@GLIBC_2.4'

Tags: c++, c, oracle, linker, linker-errors

At first I warn that I/m not programmer, but administrator only I try to understand some actions

When I installed program made by Oracle,  I got log message:

`/usr/bin/make -f ins_precomp.mk relink ORACLE_HOME=/u01/oracle/OraHome_1 EXENAME=proc/Linking /u01/oracle/OraHome_1/precomp/lib/proc

libgcc_s.so: undefined reference to`__stack_chk_fail@GLIBC_2.4'`

`ls -l

../libgcc_s.so -> /lib/libgcc_s.so.1`

so next I tried to diagnose by:

**objdump -T /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 | grep __stack_chk_fail**
`00000000      DF *UND*  00000000  GLIBC_2.4   __stack_chk_fail`

*and*

**ldd /lib/libgcc_s.so.1.ORG**
`linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00fc5000)

libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00110000)

/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00b39000)`

*and*

**objdump -T /lib/libc.so.6 |grep __stack_chk_fail**
`00c52f80 g    DF .text  0000001a  GLIBC_2.4   __stack_chk_fail`

1) I don't know why this problem occured if all symbols are inside shared libraries (mabye it isn't, please correct me, or how to check it)

when I put older library libgcc_s.so.1 without symbol __stack_chk_fail

**objdump -T /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 |grep __stack_chk_fail**
`empty output`

*everything was ok*

2) Do linker not check reference to __stack_chk_fail, because there isn't inside libgcc_s.so.1 in that case?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is:

libgcc_s.so is having the dependency on libc.so.6. This problem starts with glibc 2.4 version.

You should add -lc in the link line.

This question will give you more information.
[In Linux stubs are used for standard libraries. Why are stubs required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385555/in-linux-stubs-are-used-for-standard-libraries-why-are-stubs-required)

Comment: Much better answer than mine! +1

Comment: so where I should add -lc at the beginning or the end?

Comment: Add lc after lgcc_s in the link line.

Comment: I'm affraid that due to reason that installation scripts from Oracle are very complex, I don't know in which one I should put lc. I tried set LD_PRELOAD but it's not possible due to security, next i set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to /lib but it's not working. So I don't understand if linker can find libgcc_so.1 from /lib path why it can't find glibc inside the same directory?

Answer (score 2):

The `*UND*` in `00000000 DF *UND* 00000000 GLIBC_2.4 __stack_chk_fail` indicates that the section is referenced but not defined. So yes, you're missing the symbol.

Comment: could you explain where It should be defined because when execute on failed so: objdump -T /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 |grep UND, I obtain much more, like: 00000000      DF *UND*  00000000  GLIBC_2.0   realloc

Comment: of course symbol __stack_chk_fail is undefined in libgcc_so.1 but it's defined inside libc.so.6 so I don't understand why the warning occur