# How to create stub shared libraries on Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, binutils

Let's first explain what I mean with a stub shared library: a shared library that can be used to link against (w/ a certain interface provided by a real library) but don't contain the actual code (so has no functionality).

Along with the header files it provides everything needed to develop against the library.

Stubs can allow linking to a certain library without having the code available, but also for compatibility it can be useful to link against a stub of a certain library. See for example  [In Linux stubs are used for standard libraries. Why are stubs required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385555/in-linux-stubs-are-used-for-standard-libraries-why-are-stubs-required)

Ideally what I need is a way to generate a dummy library from a symbol map file. This map file is, in turn, generated either from an existing .so library or in the same build process.

Are there any tools for this freely available? Or would I need to roll my own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that for simple C libraries, you could use the output of `nm -D` on your real shared library to make the stub. For instance you could pipe it into a small `awk` script which defines functions of that same name, etc.

Another approach would be to make your tiny [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension to a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler which would generate the stub (e.g. in C++ or C form) when compiling the real library, or which would clear every function body (in a special mode for compiling a stub-only library). This would work for any language compiled by GCC (but requires some understanding of GCC internals, e.g. Trees and Gimples). Ask on [gcc-melt@googlegroups.com](http://groups.google.com/d/forum/gcc-melt)

However, I am not sure to understand the practical interest of such stubs. In practice a shared library has some specific coding rules and usage, and this is not verified when using stubs. To be concrete, if using Xlib, you need to call `XOpenDisplay` at first and `XCloseDisplay` at last, and such rule can't be checked with an automatically generated stub, etc...

Comment: I'm trying to do this with a huge C++ library, so I'm afraid the simple approach won't work. And indeed, the library cannot (sensibly) be used to verify anything at runtime, it's just there for linking. To provide an interface to link against although the underlying code can be different.

Comment: Then you might consider the MELT approach i.e. customize your GCC (e.g. to clear every function body).

Comment: FWIW stubs can be used to optimize a build system. In a "naive" build, you may re-link every transitive dependency of a particular library when it is rebuilt. However if the interface hasn't changed, you actually don't need to re-link anything.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Stub libraries are useful for implementing self contained source packages that can be built without requiring to install the full set of dependencies' development packages. You just ship the stubs and the headers with the source.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: A linker can not, and will not make any checks on the valid use of an API offered by a library. If a certain sequence of calls is required, like your example of `XOpenDisplay`/`XCloseDisplay` such can only be verified by actually running the program. Stub libraries are useful here, too, since they allow to build the test article on a tightly scoped build server, then transfer it to a test environment with a special validation version of the library, checking for valid use of the API.